# Construct DateTime using today's date at a specific time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'd like to get 4:30 PM of the current day. Hard-coding this way doesn't work:

```
SELECT '07242012 16:30:00.000'
```

This is proving to be more difficult than I thought it would be. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

SQL Server 2012+

```
DECLARE @d date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SELECT SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS
(
  YEAR(@d), MONTH(@d), DAY(@d), 16, 30
);
```

SQL Server 2008/2008 R2:

```
DECLARE @d date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 16.5*60, CONVERT(datetime,@d));
```

SQL Server 2000 / 2005:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 16.5*60, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));

-- or

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(9), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 112) + '16:30');

-- or

SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 16.5*60, {fn curdate()});
```

Comment: @NathanSkert I think the first code block will work in 7.0/6.5 as well, but I am not about to throw together an instance to prove it. :-)

Comment: Perfect. And for precision beyond minutes, use the DATETIMEFROMPARTS function to specify seconds and milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to cast the current date/time to a date (stripping the time off), cast it back to a datetime to allow use of datetime's overloaded `+ (plus)` and, finally cast your desired textual time to a datetime. As follows:

```
select cast(cast(sysutcdatetime() as date) as datetime) + cast('16:30' as datetime)
```

returns (when run on 11th Jan 2018):

```
2018-01-11 16:30:00.000
```

Comment: This looks like a reasonable answer, but it'd be much better if you'd add some explanation of what's going on here. A code snippet all by itself isn't as useful as a paragraph that explains what you're doing followed by code that illustrates the idea.

Comment: I have expanded the reply. Hopefully it appears to be more worthwhile now

Answer (score 0):

You can construct this as you like with day, hour, minute etc.

```
SELECT CURDATE() - interval 1 DAY + interval 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select(dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) + '20:00') as specified_date
```

> specified_date - Output Column name
>
> 20:00 - Specified time(24 hr Format -Default)
>
> getdate() - To get Today's date.