# How to get data based on today date and time?

Tags: sql-server

```
select * from hockey_stats where game_date between '11/3/2012 12:00:00' and '11/5/2012 15:00:00' order by game_date desc;
```

How to get data based on today date and time between 12:00:00 to 15:00:00?

Comment: SELECT GETDATE();

Comment: Should guide you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635428/construct-datetime-using-todays-date-at-a-specific-time.

Comment: @Will , I want to select data based on time range and only current date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
game_date BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),121) + 'T12:00:00' AND CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),121) + 'T15:00:00'
```

Note, however, I recommend using `>=` and `<` syntax when using times. I **assume** you wants all times after `12:00` and *before* `15:00`, which would be:

```
WHERE game_date >= CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),121) + 'T12:00:00'
  AND game_date <= CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),121) + 'T15:00:00'
```

*This does assume that `game_date` is a `datetime` (or variant) datatype, and not a `varchar`; but then why would it not be?*