# Check for data before next day 10 AM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Need to implement logic If actual is <= Next day 10 AM then its 1 else 0

This is my test record

```
Create table #tmp (ID int, Actual Datetime)

Insert into #tmp values (1,'2022-01-09 13:55:29.340')

Insert into #tmp values (2,'2022-01-07 13:55:29.340')

Insert into #tmp values (3,'2022-01-08 13:55:29.340')

select * from #tmp
```

Expected Output

```
ID  Actual                    1/0   
1   2022-01-09 13:55:29.340    0  
2   2022-01-07 13:55:29.340    1  
3   2022-01-08 13:55:29.340    1
```

For ID 1 it should be 0 because Actual is 06 and it is after next day 10 AM. ID 2 and 3 should be 1 because it is less than or equal to next day before 10 AM.

I am stuck in how to check 10 AM for next day. please help me on this.

Comment: Are 06 bigger than NextDate and 07 and 08 less than NextDate ?! Are you sure ?!

Comment: See this post for examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635428/construct-datetime-using-todays-date-at-a-specific-time

Comment: Your text and your expected data seems to be a bit inconsistent. Assuming today is the 2022-01-07, then "next day 10 am" is `2022-01-08 10:00:00`. Then how is `2022-01-06 13:55` *not* less than that, and how is `2022-01-08 13:55` *less than* that?

Comment: It would be helpful to indicate the "current time" that relates to the expected results as we don't know your time zone or when you ran that query

Comment: @MartinSmith, I edited the answer and an appropriate answer be returned

Comment: There is a typo on ID =1 it should be 9

Comment: Your example is still inconsistent. If today is the 7th of Jan, how is 8th of Jan 13:55 less then "next day 10 am". Please specify your reference date, you are calculating the "next day" from ...

Answer (score 1):

Use this query :

```
select *,case when Actual<=DATEADD(HOUR, 10, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) then 0 else 1 end as '1/0'  from #tmp
```

today date is 2022-01-07 and my result is:

```
ID  Actual                     1/0
1   2022-01-06 13:55:29.340     0
2   2022-01-07 13:55:29.340     0
3   2022-01-08 13:55:29.340     1
```

If you want to compare with today then:

```
select *,case when Actual<=DATEADD(HOUR, 10, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) then 0 else 1 end as '1/0'  from #tmp
```

Output:

```
ID  Actual                     1/0
1   2022-01-06 13:55:29.340     0
2   2022-01-07 13:55:29.340     1
3   2022-01-08 13:55:29.340     1
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But output is not what I am looking for

Comment: I updated this answer for what you want. This generates your output. :)

Comment: Everything is coming as 1

Comment: @SaeedEmamYari The question says "*If actual is <= Next day 10 AM then its 1 else 0*" Your case is doing it the other way around ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
     , Flag = iif(Actual < dateadd(day, datediff(day, '10:00', getdate()) + 1, '10:00'), 1, 0);
  From #tmp
```